# How do I test call and apply functions in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Here's my *callnapply.js* file

```
const callAndApply = {
  caller(object, method, nameArg, ageArg, tShirtSizeArg) {
    method.call(object, nameArg, ageArg, tShirtSizeArg);
  },
  applier(object, method, argumentsArr) {
    method.apply(object, argumentsArr);
  },
};
module.exports = callAndApply;
```

And here's a snippet from the test file which contains the non-working test:

```
const callnapply = require('./callnapply');

test('testing Function.prototype.call as mock function', () => {
    const outer = jest.fn(); 
    const name = 'Aakash';
    const age = 22;
    const tee = 'M';
    callnapply.caller(this, outer, name, age, tee);
    expect(outer.call).toHaveBeenCalledWith(name, age, tee);
});
```

How do I write the test to check if the `method` that I am passing is, in fact, being called by the `Function.prototype.call` function only? I want to check whether `.call()` is being called and not some other implementation that has been written for the `method` call.

Comment: Sadly the other answer was deleted. I'll just wrap it up in this comment: you can also use a specific context to apply your function to and test this context in the end. (issue would be you cannot know if you test `apply` or `call` method)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mock the `.call()` method itself:

```
const outer = function() {}
outer.call = jest.fn()
```

Then you can do usual jest mock tests on `outer.call`.

Here is the working test file:

```
const callnapply = require('./callnapply');

test('testing Function.prototype.call as mock function', () => {
    const outer = function() {};
    outer.call = jest.fn();
    const name = 'Aakash';
    const age = 22;
    const tee = 'M';
    callnapply.caller(this, outer, name, age, tee);
    expect(outer.call).toHaveBeenCalledWith(this, name, age, tee);
});
```

See [this working REPL](https://repl.it/@BuonOmo/test-call-method-with-jest).

Comment: Lemme just add the code up front so that people do not need to go to that excellent REPL. Review it and you can have the bounty.

Comment: I edited again in order to match your question's code